# variable not set during before_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem understand the order of events that are causing my value `selectedplan` to not be set in my set_expiration_date in my model.

In my model I have a before_create that sets an expiration date:

```
 selectedplan = ""
 before_create :set_expiration_date

def set_expiration_date
  puts  self.amount_and_duration(selectedplan).second.days // here value is nil
  self.expiration =  Date.today + self.getAmountAndDuration.second.days
end
```

... in my save_with_payment function my selectedplan variable contains the correct value

```
def save_with_payment(chosenadduration)
      if valid?
        selectedplan = chosenadduration
        ... here value is OK

      )
        save!

    end
```

But in the set_expiration_date it's not set. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should replace:

```
selectedplan = chosenadduration
```

with:

```
self.selectedplan = chosenadduration
```

To tell ruby you're not working with a local variable.

In this case `selectedplan` should be an `attr_accessor`, to tune depending on your needs.